Connection to SQL Server from .NET Core on Ubuntu fails with SSL/TLS handshake error
I have a .NET Core console application that connects to a SQL Server database. The application works fine on Windows, but I'm encountering an SSL/TLS handshake failure when running it on an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS VM .
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var connectionString = "Data Source=DB*****;Initial Catalog=efdfdApi;User Id=useridd;Password=*****;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=true;Application Intent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=false";
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection successful!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Connection failed: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}


Issue: When I execute dotnet TestConnection.dll on my Ubuntu VM, I get the following error:
Connection failed: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)

Additional Information:

I've verified that the connection string is correct and works on Windows.

I suspect there might be SSL/TLS configuration differences between Windows and Ubuntu that I need to address.


    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.2.1" />





I used these
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev ca-certificates libkrb5-dev
sudo apt-get install openssl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev ca-certificates libkrb5-dev
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates

What steps should I take to troubleshoot and resolve this SSL/TLS handshake failure when connecting to SQL Server from .NET Core on Ubuntu?
